# Conditional Deserialization of either a Dictionary or a List of Objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am sending a GET request to a Rest API that returns some JSON in two different formats (based on some external setting that I can't influence).
I can either receive:

```
"content": {
    "fields": [
     {
         "name": "test1",
         "value": 1
     },
     {
         "name": "test2",
         "value": "test"
     },
     {
         "name": "test3",
         "value": "test",
         "links": [...]
     }
   ]
}
```

or

```
"content": {
  "test1": 1,
  "test2": "test",
  "test3": "test"
}
```

You can see that I receive either a list of objects containing `name` and `value` properties (along with some other properties like `links`), or I receive a single object containing key-value pairs as in a Dictionary.  I now want to know if there is a way to conditionally deserialize the JSON into a class with `Dictionary<string, string>` and `List<Field>` properties like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Content
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Type of the Content
    /// </summary>
    public string _Type { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

and fill either the dictionary or the list of fields depending on the JSON.

Comment: a custom jsonconverter that can inspect the json and extract the desired format

Comment: Im geusing it should be a public Dictionary<string, List<Fields>> Dictionary { get; set; }

Comment: No it should be Dictionary<string,string> as that is what I am expecting. The Fields Class has way more members than I need here. @Nkosi could you give me an Example or link that points me in the right direction

Comment: @Brezelmann you can find details in documentation https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: @Nkosi I checked your Idea. I am not sure how to do it in my case because i have two quite different data structures with either a Dictionary or a List and one of those will always be null because I can either get a Dictionary of Data or a List of Data but never both.

Comment: @Brezelmann Which is why you need to decide which one you want and have the second converted to the other when identified.

Comment: That way, while the data being returned can be of different formats, your strongly typed code remains constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this situation by creating a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1.htm) for your `Content` class as shown below.  It works by loading the `content` portion of the JSON into a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and checking for the presence of the `fields` property to determine how to populate the `Content` instance.

```
public class ContentConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Content);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        Content content = new Content();
        if (jo["fields"] != null)
        {
            // if the fields property is present, we have a list of fields
            content.Fields = jo["fields"].ToObject<List<Field>>(serializer);
            content._Type = "Fields";
        }
        else
        {
            // fields property is not present so we have a simple dictionary
            content.Dictionary = jo.Properties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (string)p.Value);
            content._Type = "Dictionary";
        }
        return content;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I was not sure how you wanted to handle the `_Type` property, so I just set it to either "Fields" or "Dictionary" to indicate which property was populated.  Feel free to change it to suit your needs.

To use the converter, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `Content` class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ContentConverter))]
public class Content
{
    ...
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/geg5fA

Comment: Works really nice. A good Example and a real good explanation. Thank you @Brian Rogers